# After import my own module in colaboratory, how can i use it?

Tags: python, google-colaboratory

I have already seen this example.

https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1uvHuizCBqFgvbCwEhK7FvU8JW0AfxgJw

However, it return a JSON file when i cat the `.py` file.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swJYk.png)

The `test.py` is like.

```
def a(x,y):
  z = x + y
  return z
```

And i can't  use the module.

Comment: Make sure they are in the same folder and you are colling the correct test.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your image suggests that you saved a *notebook* with a title of "test.py" into your Google Drive, so it is expected that it is a JSON file (notebooks are stored as JSON). I suspect what you really wanted to do is more like:

```
%%writefile test.py
def a(x, y):
  z = x + y
  return z
```

to write a plain-text file.

The reason your `import test` succeeds is that there's a standard-library module by that name (https://docs.python.org/2/library/test.html#module-test). I suggest you use a different name for your `.py` file to disambiguate :)

Comment: It worked.
BUT, it creates a new .py file for me in the 'content' folder when I using the %%writefile command. And, I have to change the append to the 'content' but not the 'gdrive'. However, in the example, he can import the file from his drive.
WHY?

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking; if it's why the example works while your initial post's code doesn't, it's because the example uses a file named "mylib.py" while you use "test.py", and "mylib" is not already a system module's name, while "test" is.